# DataTables - Pass Array to Another Page

Tags: arrays, datatable, get

I'm trying to pass an array of data from DataTables from one page to another using the following script on page 1:

```
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
            var trowdata = console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
            sessionStorage.setItem('myArray', trowdata);
            window.location.href = 'bmdrecord2.php';
            return false;
        } );
```

The console.log( table.row( this ).data() ); code returns data in the following example format:

> Object { id: "3", name: "Jason Robertson", position: "Junior Developer", start_date: "2014/01/31" }

and trying to receive the data using the code on page 2 as follows:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var myArray = sessionStorage.getItem('myArray');
        })
```

and display the data using the code on page 2 as follows:

```
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:25%"><italic><script>document.write(Object.keys[0](myArray));</script></italic></td>   // To display id:
            <td style="width:75%"><strong><script>document.write(Object.values[0](myArray));</script></strong></td>   // To display 3
          <tr>
            <td style="width:25%"><italic><script>document.write(Object.keys[1](myArray));</script></italic></td>  // To display name:
            <td style="width:75%"><strong><script>document.write(Object.values[1](myArray));</script></strong></td>   // To display Jason Robertson
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:25%"><italic><script>document.write(Object.keys[2](myArray));</script></italic></td>   // To display position:
            <td style="width:75%"><strong><script>document.write(Object.values[2](myArray));</script></strong></td>   // To display Junior Developer
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:25%"><italic><script>document.write(Object.keys[3](myArray));</script></italic></td>   // To display start_date:
            <td style="width:75%"><strong><script>document.write(Object.values[3](myArray));</script></strong></td>   // To display 2014/01/31
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

When I click on the link and am taken to page 2 the error: ReferenceError: myArray is not defined is displayed for every instance of myArray referred to. I don't understand why the trowdata variable containing the array is not being passed to page 2 despite the array data being passed to the console.log.

I'd appreciate any assistance advising where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to arrive at a solution to the problem using the following code:

**Page 1** *(passing the array to Page 2):*

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var rowArray = table.row( this ).data();
        localStorage.setItem( 'bmddata', JSON.stringify( rowArray ) );
        window.location.href = 'bmdrecord.php';
        return false;
    } );
```

The following **ind.js** file was then created and saved under the js folder in the root directory of the website:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bmdArray = "";
  var bmdArray = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('bmddata') );
  document.getElementById("indKey0").innerHTML = Object.keys(bmdArray)[0];
  document.getElementById("indValue0").innerHTML = Object.values(bmdArray)[0];
  document.getElementById("indKey1").innerHTML = Object.keys(bmdArray)[1];
  document.getElementById("indValue1").innerHTML = Object.values(bmdArray)[1];
  document.getElementById("indKey2").innerHTML = Object.keys(bmdArray)[2];
  document.getElementById("indValue2").innerHTML = Object.values(bmdArray)[2];
  document.getElementById("indKey3").innerHTML = Object.keys(bmdArray)[3];
  document.getElementById("indValue3").innerHTML = Object.values(bmdArray)[3];
})
```

Then the following code was used to display the data on **page 2**:

```
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="toTitle" style="width:25%"><span id="indKey0"></span>:</th>   <!-- To display id:  -->
          <td id="indValue0" style="width:75%"><strong></strong></td>   <!-- To display 3  -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="toTitle" style="width:25%"><span id="indKey1"></span>:</th>    <!-- To display name:  -->
          <td id="indValue1" style="width:75%"><strong></strong></td>   <!-- To display Jason Robertson  -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="toTitle" style="width:25%"><span id="indKey2"></span>:</th>    <!-- To display position:  -->
          <td id="indValue2" style="width:75%"><strong></strong></td>   <!-- To display Junior Developer  -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="toTitle" style="width:25%"><span id="indKey3"></span>:</th>    <!-- To display start_date:  -->
          <td id="indValue3" style="width:75%"><strong></strong></td>   <!-- To display 2014/01/31  -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="toTitle" style="width:25%"><span id="indKey4"></span>:</th>    <!-- To display Salary:  -->
          <td id="indValue4" style="width:75%"><strong></strong></td>   <!-- To display £20,000  -->
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

...

```
<script src="js/ind.js"></script>
```